# How can add key shortcut on the MenuItem header wpf xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to search on internet but I not find anything. I want to show on the user when is click on the menu in menuitem what is the shortcut for this command (menuitem).

[image]

For example I want to make like "Build Solution" and is can see what shortcut is have.

Here is my xaml what I try:

```
<MenuItem Name="HelpMenuItem" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" MouseLeave="HelpButtonMouseLeave" MouseEnter="HelpButtonMouseEnter" Header="{catel:LanguageBinding ResourceName=HelpSubMenu}" Command="{Binding Help}">
    <MenuItem.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="F1" Gesture="F1" Modifiers="Control" Command="Help" />
    </MenuItem.InputBindings>
</MenuItem>
```

Is it possible to make it only with xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `InputGestureText` property of the `MenuItem`. According to MSDN it designed exactly for this purporse (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<MenuItem Name="HelpMenuItem" Header="Help" InputGestureText="F1" />
```

**Edit**

Unfortunately it's not works for root `MenuItems`. For this case you can write something like this.

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Help" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Ctrl+F1" />
        </DockPanel>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: In my case is not visualize the F1.

Comment: Maybe there are some problems with `Header` binding or `MenuItem` style. Did you applied style for `MenuItem`?

Comment: No. In the mouse events only I change the background on menu item. I change and Header to be Header="_Help", and again is not working

Comment: I've tested in many cases and it's not working only in the root `MenuItem` of MainMenu, but it should work in submenus.

Comment: I've added another solution.